# $\mathbb{R}$ represented using an infinite union of finite sets containing reals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $S_1$, $S_2$, $\dots$ are sets of real numbers and if $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}{S_j} = \mathbb{R}$ then one of the sets $S_j$ must have infinitely many elements.

I believe at least one of the $S_j$ must be an infinite set, but I can't work out a proof. What's the trick I'm missing?

Comment: If all $S_j$ were finite, then their sum would be countable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that all sets were finite, the union of countably many finite sets is countable, but the real numbers are not.

[This argument uses the axiom of choice, however it is true without the axiom of choice that a countable union of finite sets of real numbers is countable]

Comment: Ahha, I incorrectly believed an infinite union of sets is UNcountable. I read up on countable sets and this makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In fact something stronger is true: at least one of $S_i$ has to be uncountable.

It is a standard fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable. You could for instance enumerate elements of $S_i$ so that:
$$ S_i = \{ S_i^{j} \}_{j \in \mathbb{N} } $$
and then arrange $\{ S_i^{j}: i,j \in \mathbb{N} \} = \bigcup_{i} S_i$ ordering first according to $i+j$ and then $i$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable, it can't be that all $S_i$ are countable, and you are done.

Comment: Of course this is not something that matters for most people, but it is consistent without the axiom of choice that the real numbers are a countable union of countable sets.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila - thanks for this rather surprising insight. Mathematics without AC is apparently even stranger than I thought.

Comment: @Feanor: Yeah, sometimes it is even stranger than mathematics *with* AC :)